# HTML entities encoding entity numbers

Tags: perl, html-entities

I have a test string like :

```
my $input = "testing &test &#8360;";
my $output = HTML::Entities::encode_entities($str,"<>&\"'");
```

The desired output is

```
testing &amp;test &#8360;
```

But HTML::Entities::encode_entities is encoding this into

```
testing &amp;test &amp;#8360;
```

To summarize, I want the HTML::Entities to encode the "&" character only if it does not represent an HTML entity number.

Comment: What is `$str`? Is that a typo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to *decode* the string first, then *encode* it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings; use v5.10;
use HTML::Entities ();
my $input = "testing &test &#8360;";
$input = HTML::Entities::encode( HTML::Entities::decode( $input ) );
say $input;
```

The result is

```
testing &amp;test &#x20A8;
```

`20A8` is the hexadecimal version of `8360`.